# What is the most Pythonic way to organise constants?

Tags: python, constants, packaging, marshmallow, code-structure

I use `marshmallow` and have a series of object serialization. Because of technical reasons, the names of the field and class can be the same.

For example,

```
class Sample(Schema):
    SampleField = fields.Nested(SampleField)

class SampleField(Schema):
   # Some other fields
```

When I need to reference `SampleField` as a string in the code. I create constant and name it `SAMPLE_FIELD = SampleField`. Often I need to have the same constant in both places in the definition class and where it is used as a field.

How to organize it the way, it will not become messy?

Comment: Why do you assign `SampleField` to `SAMPLE_FIELD`? Do you re-assign `SampleField` to a class after that?

Comment: @lainatnavi Nope, the idea is to make dictionaries that further serialize and validated by `marshmallow schema`. I sometimes need to reference name of the field, so it will be serialized properly from the `dict`. One of the scenarios, I need to remove `SamleField` from the dictionary in certain occasions.

Answer (score 0):

The marshmallow field does not have to be named after the field name in serialiazed data.

Would this solve your problem?

```
class SampleSchema(Schema):
    sample_field = fields.Nested(SampleFieldSchema, data_key='SampleField')

class SampleFieldSchema(Schema):
   # Some other fields
```